# Couldn't able to generate coverage report by aggregating all the modules

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report-aggregate (report-aggregate) on project distribution: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report-aggregate for parameter dataFileIncludes: Cannot assign configuration entry 'dataFileIncludes' with value '**/jacoco-unit.exec' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.util.List -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

pom.xml

```
          <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFileIncludes>**/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFileIncludes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I couldn't able to aggregate all modules and generate a single code coverage report

Did anyone face this issue? what's wrong in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that the `dataFileIncludes` is supposed to be a list.
This is also [defined](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/jacoco-maven-plugin/src/org/jacoco/maven/ReportAggregateMojo.java) in jacoco maven plugin source code.

So you can try to map it to the list by following [this document](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Lists):

```
          <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-aggregate</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFileIncludes>
                           <dataFileInclude>**/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFileInclude> 
                        </dataFileIncludes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Ya...The data type is saying it should be `list` but  [this](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html#dataFileIncludes) documentation doesn't have this `dataFileInclude` tag. I thought to by default it will take all `.exec` files as list format